# Lock screen widget and wallpaper

Tags: android-versions, motorola-moto-e

I'm currently using a Moto E with Android version 5.1. I would like to change the clock widget on the lock screen with a customized one and even lock screen wallpaper. Is there a way to do so?

[image: IMG:]

I'm using Nova Launcher Prime. Can you help me out please?

Comment: Do you not want to use custom lockscreens? They offers such features.

Comment: @Firelord I would prefer but can you recommend me some